# How can I import a python package or __init__.py file using the full path?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-import

I have a package: pyfoo in a directory /home/user/somedir

The package is a normal one with 
'/home/user/somedir/pyfoo/__init__.py'

I would like to be able to import this module using its full-path '/home/user/somedir/pyfoo/'

How to do this for non-package modules is shown in: 
[How to import a module given the full path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path)

But I seem to be unable to get this to work when the module is a package.

---

The very odd use case I found for this is I was embed deep into a script execution before writing to a file with h5py.

I had to uninstall h5py and reinstall a parallel version with openmpi, but even though it was uninstalled h5py(serial) was still in memory. I did not want to restart, because the script took a long time. I attempted to reload the module, but it did not work. I also tried to import it from its filename using the directory and with __init__.py, but I got relative import errors.  I even tried adding the new install location to sys.path and executing a normal import, but that too failed.

I already have a import_from_filepath function in my personal utility library, and I'd like to add the import_from_dirpath as well, but I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out how its done.

---

Here is a script illustrating the issue:

```
    # Define two temporary modules that are not in sys.path
    # and have the same name but different values.
    import sys, os, os.path
    def ensuredir(path):
        if not os.path.exists(path):
            os.mkdir(path)
    ensuredir('tmp')
    ensuredir('tmp/tmp1')
    ensuredir('tmp/tmp2')
    ensuredir('tmp/tmp1/testmod')
    ensuredir('tmp/tmp2/testmod')
    with open('tmp/tmp1/testmod/__init__.py', 'w') as file_:
        file_.write('foo = \"spam\"\nfrom . import sibling')
    with open('tmp/tmp1/testmod/sibling.py', 'w') as file_:
        file_.write('bar = \"ham\"')
    with open('tmp/tmp2/testmod/__init__.py', 'w') as file_:
        file_.write('foo = \"eggs\"\nfrom . import sibling')
    with open('tmp/tmp1/testmod/sibling.py', 'w') as file_:
        file_.write('bar = \"jam\"')

    # Neither module should be importable through the normal mechanism
    try:
        import testmod
        assert False, 'should fail'
    except ImportError as ex:
        pass

    # Try temporarilly adding the directory of a module to the path
    sys.path.insert(0, 'tmp/tmp1')
    testmod1 = __import__('testmod', globals(), locals(), 0)
    sys.path.remove('tmp/tmp1')
    print(testmod1.foo)
    print(testmod1.sibling.bar)

    sys.path.insert(0, 'tmp/tmp2')
    testmod2 = __import__('testmod', globals(), locals(), 0)
    sys.path.remove('tmp/tmp2')
    print(testmod2.foo)
    print(testmod2.sibling.bar)

    assert testmod1.foo == "spam"
    assert testmod1.sibling.bar == "ham"

    # Fails, returns spam
    assert testmod2.foo == "eggs"
    assert testmod2.sibling.bar == "jam"
```

The sys.path method does not import via file path. It defaults to importing the previously loaded module.

Comment: Have you tried appending `/home/user/somedir/` to `sys.path`?

Comment: Yes, and it did not seem to work.

Comment: What did you try exactly?

Comment: @sirfz See the small test example that I posted.

Comment: Use full paths and also make sure you have `__init__.py` in your packages' dirs.

Answer (score 1):

In general you don't do imports from absolute paths in Python. It is possible but it break things like the imports in that module.

What you do is to adapt the `PYTHONPATH`. It tells python where to look for the stuff you want to import. You can set the environmental variable `PYTHONPATH` before calling your script or you can see and manipulate it at runtime. To do so, change `sys.path`. It's a list, you can `append()` other paths.

An other option is to use virtual environments they offer a special python environments for different projects and project setups. Read http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/ to get an idea of it.

If you still want to import by path, read [How to import a module given the full path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path) .